# Cannot get ApplePay to work on Woocommerce and Square

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, applepay, square

I'm building a site for a client using WordPress and Woocommerce. They use Square are their payment provider. They want to offer Apple Pay. They tell me they have set up Apple Pay on their Square account (I don't have access to it). I have installed the Square for Woocommerce plugin successfully and it is working on everything but ApplePay. GooglePay comes up and can be used, but ApplePay remains unavailable (the button is in there, but set with display:none and when this CSS is changed to show the button it can be seen but the button still does nothing).

I read that ApplePay will only work on Safari on desktop, and I'm testing with Safari. It still does not work.

On the admin side of WordPress, an alert is shown at the top of the screen that says "Apple Pay is not available with Square - there was a problem with registering your store domain with Square/Apple Pay". It then tells me to look at the log files.

I read that some sort of verification file is required, but the client tells me there is nothing on their Square account to indicate that. They select a button apparently, and no files, merchant ID or anything else is mentioned anywhere.

The log files do not mention ApplyPay at all.

Can anyone please advise a next step? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Do you have Apple Pay enabled for Safari on your device? Do they apply to tos of Applepay ? As for the file upload the apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association file to the .well-known folder in your document root. When they config the Applepay on theyr account should have option to add domain and option to download that file.

Comment: Also when adding the domain make sure if its www version you have to to add it with www

Comment: Yes, Apple Pay is enabled on my Safari and I have a valid card in the wallet. As I said, I have read elsewhere people talking about uploading a verification file, but my client tells me that there is nothing they can find in their Square account that allows them to set domain or download a file (I don't have access to their Square account, so I don''t know what they're doing, or able to do). I can find no Square documentation that explains such a process. Do you have links to such documentation? Add the domain to where?

Comment: I think that is located on developer dashboard https://developer.squareup.com/us/en